# link to my app always redirects to 404-page

Tags: facebook

I am trying to show django-nonrel wellcome-page on my first facebook iframe app. Canvas URL points to this html-page hosted on AppEngine.

But when I follow the link of my app it always redirects me to 404 page. why this happens?

Comment: What does tracing the HTTPS requests tell you, is Facebook redirecting the user to an invalid URL on your server? 
There's really not enough information here to know what's going on

Comment: there is 302 response and then loads http://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php page. I dont see any request to my application on appengine.

Comment: This sounds like a configuration issue with your app - are you sure you've configured the callback URL correctly?

Comment: I am not sure. I have been browsing configuration for a long time, reading documentation, but there is no such a thing as "callback URL". [And by the way current app settings looks much different as settings in blog tutorials.] The only things in basic and advanced settings are "Deauthorize Callback", "Canvas URL" and "secure canvas URL".

Comment: Of those, your canvas URL is the one most likely to be set incorrectly - that's the URL Facebook will call to get the content to display at apps.facebook.com/your_app_name 
The tab content when your app is installed on a page is pulled from whatever you configure as the **Page Tab URL** (on the Basic tab of your app settings, under 'Page Tab'

Comment: THanks for your answers. But I m sure i set url correctly. Maybe facebook waits for something in response which is not written in tutorial [not only html]? Or there are another settings which I haven't noticed.